# One machine recognized disk as corrupt, works fine on another

Tags: hard-disk, disk

I have a Western Digital USB hard drive which I typically leave connected to a Raspberry Pi. Today I noticed that the drive wasn't mounted anymore, and didn't see anything in the syslog to explain why. When I ran `sudo mount /dev/sdc /media/pi/media-2/` to re-mount it, I got:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

And `sudo fsck /dev/sdc` gave

```
fsck from util-linux 2.29.2
e2fsck 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sdc
```

When I connect it to my laptop running Ubuntu 18.04, it mounts just fine and `fsck` returns:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
media-2: clean, 1175/122093568 files, 422501325/488369920 blocks
```

On the pi, I tried connecting it to each of the USB ports and it didn't make any difference. Any idea why it works on one machine and not another?

Comment: you should run lsblk on both systems to double-check you're running your command on the same block device. Hint: "Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sdc"

Comment: could perhaps be power-supply related.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! It looks like they were using the same block device, but the rPi is a temporary stand-in for a more substantial machine that I'm building, so I'm going to hope that it's a power-supply issue and see if everything magically works fine with the new one